# Raspberry Pi 4 - Failed to start (squished text situation)

Tags: raspbian

[image]

My Raspberry Pi 4 has Raspbian Buster installed and everything was working fine. 
The last change I made was to the `/etc/fstab` file relating to booting an external USB drive.
Now when I boot up I get a message that says something like `"Failed to start....base?"` - but I can't read this because the text is squished (technical term). I've tried resizing the screen etc but it looks like this is what's actually being sent via HDMI. (see picture).

Are there any experts out there why know what this message says so that I can start checking for a solution?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: Hello and welcome – You should add an image better than this one which is not clear to read logs.

Comment: Yes - that's the whole point of my post - there's no way of reading this text - its not the picture that is the problem - this is how it looks on the screen.

Comment: This is weird, indeed. Have you the possibility to try to boot with a newly flashed SD card?

Comment: Ok thanks anyway - I just gave up and started from scratch with a fresh image. It's working now, but I've wasted a week setting the pi up! It was definitely a display issue as I tried on another monitor and still had the squished text. Thanks, Brian

Comment: Please make an answer about your solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.